How to avoid an audible click when concatenating two mp4 files?
I am using a typical ffmpeg command to concat two mp4 files:
ffmpeg -y -safe 0 -f concat -i !list.txt -c copy out.mp4

However,sometimes I can hear a "click" sound at the point where the two audio tracks join, because obviously a "level jump" occurs as the two audio-samples collide. Is it possible to have a very short fade-out at the end of the 1st clip and a very short fade-in at the start of the 2nd clip when concatenating?

You need to use the afade out and afade in filter to create new files, and then concat them
Command to ADD fade-out to the first clip
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -af "afade=t=out:st=<fade_start_time>:d=<fade_duration>" -c:v copy output1_faded.mp4

Command to Add fade-in to the second clip
ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -af "afade=t=in:st=0:d=<fade_duration>" -c:v copy output2_faded.mp4


This transcodes both audio streams.  In theory it would be possible to just encode one audio frame of new AAC data to bridge the discontinuity between tracks, but that might require specialized software.  But anyway, you should at least mention -c:a libfdk_aac and/or link https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC / Is FDK-AAC still better than FFmpeg's native AAC encoder? (yes).  Or since you're transcoding anyway, you could just go to Opus in an MKV or WEBM file, instead of AAC at all.
